# Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438) at changing caption of a label

Tags: excel, vba, object

I want to create some sort of status checklist while the vba is working. First i create the Label and then i will keep changing the captions on it.
The problem i have is that if i run the 2 module manually using Developer -> Macros -> Run, all is working as expected but if i run them in a vba:
Call  StatusCreator
Call  StatusLabel1
I get the Error Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438).
Using the Step by Step i get the error at line "Set Btn = .OLEObjects.Add" But i get the error only if both the modules are Called at the same time with vba

Module 1

```
    Sub StatusCreator()
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim ctop#, cleft#, cht#, cwdth#
Dim sht    As Worksheet
Dim Btn    As OLEObject
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    With Range("H15:L37")
    ctop = .Top
    cleft = .Left
    cht = .Height
    cwdth = .Width
    End With
With sht
    Set Btn = .OLEObjects.Add(classtype:="Forms.Label.1", Left:=cleft, Top:=ctop, 
Width:=cwdth, Height:=cht)
End With
DoEvents
DoEvents

With Btn                                      'set the properties
    .Name = "Label1"
    .Object.Caption = "Starting...."
    .Object.Font.Size = 24
    .Object.Font.Bold = False
    .Object.BackColor = RGB(0, 244, 0)
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
DoEvents
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End Sub
```

Module 2

```
Sub StatusLabel1()
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Worksheets("Main").Label1.Caption = _
"                          Status" & vbNewLine & _
"    DefinePaths....................Running" & vbNewLine & _
"    CreateFolders.................Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    CloseWorkbooks.............Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Shippments to xy........Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Scrap Report....................Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Shippment to xz...Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Shippments to zz........Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Database Update.............Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Database Backup.............Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Clear temporary files.......Waiting" & vbNewLine & _
"    Start next schedule..........Waiting"
DoEvents
DoEvents
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are is the  `Call StatusCreator` code located; module, sheet, workbook ? Code works for me in workbook.

Comment: Are you sure that manually added **an activeX** type label? For an activeX control, `Worksheets("Main").Label1` does not return an object. Since your first code added an `OLEObject` label, it should be set in a different way: Please, try `Worksheets("Main").OLEObjects("Label1").Object.Caption = "...".

Comment: @CDP1802 i tried placing them in Module and in Sheet Code but got the same problems

Comment: @FaneDuru this `Worksheets("Main").OLEObjects("Label1").Object.Caption = "..." is working, Thank you. I was trying to solve it for about 5 hours, i did not realize that this is the problem.